# Dalvik error using Doc to HTML android docx4j

Tags: android, docx4j

I am just using the code at `https://github.com/plutext/AndroidDocxToHtml` for converting doc to html but I am getting `Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1`. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete `serializer-2.7.1.jar` from the `libs` folder, remove it from your dependencies or build path. Doing only this may work for some people, but I had another error :

`(Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex:)`

If you get this error, just add `jumboMode=true` to your `project.properties` (if you work with Eclipse)

Hope this answer doesn't come too late!

Answer (score 0):

This library allows converting only .DOCX files.
DOC files is unsupported in this library.